# qTranslate Importer “Please save the qTranslate settings to the database first”

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, wpml, qtranslate

I'm developing multilingual site in Wordpress and Woocommerce, I have purchased WPML plugin because now I have qTranslate but it doesn't work correctly and it has no support.

I'm using qTranslate Importer plugin but this error is coming every time when I start it :

```
Please save the qTranslate settings to the database first.
```

Please help me in this regard or suggest me is there any other way to convert contents of Wordpress Site from qTranslate to WPML